# How to see which div the cursor is on in JavaScript for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, mobile

I am working on a game, and I want to see which `div` the cursor is over using JavaScript. This is the very early access version of the page: https://gerhardadler.no/make_it_rain.html

This is the thing i currently have that works for pc's.

HTML:

```
<div onmouseover="kolonne(1)" id="kolonne_en"></div>
<div onmouseover="kolonne(2)" id="kolonne_to"></div>
<div onmouseover="kolonne(3)" id="kolonne_tre"></div>
<div onmouseover="kolonne(4)" id="kolonne_fire"></div>
<div onmouseover="kolonne(5)" id="kolonne_fem"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function kolonne(kolonne) {

 if (kolonne == 1) {
 spillerElem.style.left = "0px";
 pos = 0;

 } else if (kolonne == 2) {
    spillerElem.style.left = "100px";
    pos = 100;
   } else if (kolonne == 3) {
      spillerElem.style.left = "200px";
      pos = 200;
     } else if (kolonne == 4) {
        spillerElem.style.left = "300px";
        pos = 300;
       } else if (kolonne == 5) {
          spillerElem.style.left = "400px";
          pos = 400;
         } 

}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use `TouchEvents` methods
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_touchevent.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events). Add a common class to all the elements and then use `querySelector` to get them.Iterate over it and attach touch event

```
doucment.querySelectorAll('.elem').forEach((item) => {

  item.addEventListener('touchstart', (evt) => {
    const getVal = this.dataset.kolonner;
    // rest of the code

  })
})

<div data-kolonne="1" class='elem' id="kolonne_en"></div>
<div data-kolonne="2" class='elem' id="kolonne_to"></div>
<div data-kolonne="3" class='elem' id="kolonne_tre"></div>
<div data-kolonne="4" class='elem' id="kolonne_fire"></div>
<div data-kolonne="5" class='elem' id="kolonne_fem"></div>
```